Trouble getting the formula to return an accurate %, keeps rounding up
This should have been a simple measurement.
% test = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('new_contractline'[Document License Area (ha)]),
    SUM('new_kpis'[Value])
) 

returns 1.00, when the actual value should be .9974
This formula:
%%% Document License Area (ha) divided by Value = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('new_contractline'[Document License Area (ha)]),
    SUM('new_kpis'[Value]),
    0
) *100

Returns 99.74, when i actually want .9974
What I don't understand is why i can't seem to get a value of .9974, I've tried many different approaches, and no help from ChatGPT.
Other formulas I've tried:
%%% Document License Area (ha) divided by Value = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('new_contractline'[Document License Area (ha)]),
    SUM('new_kpis'[Value]),
    0
) *.01

returns .01
A seperate measure that takes the %%% Document License Area (ha) divided by Value * .01, returns 1.00.  I've tried showing more decimal points, but it's not giving me anything else.
What else do I need to check, and I really don't understand why this calculation is behaving this way.
I should add that this formula:
%%% Document License Area (ha) divided by Value = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('new_contractline'[Document License Area (ha)]),
    SUM('new_kpis'[Value]),
    0
) 

returns 1.00

I think you can set up the decimal numbers. It shows 2 decimals by default.

if you want to show more decimals, you can change the number of decimal places in the Measure tools.


As @Ryan has pointed out - it is down to formatting and decimal places.
Please mark his answer as Accepted.
Just wanted to share these two snips:


